# I need help by editing a role color in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to edit a Role with discord.js. I checked the docs and this should work:

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "863772779039424544"); 
await role.edit({
    color: '#8585ff'
})
```

but the role doesn't get's edited and I don't know why. The same code exists also few lines above and the work.

I don't know, what I should do now.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you show us the whole function in which you're using that code? `role.edit` call looks fine to me according to [Discord API — Role Edit](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=edit) docs.

Comment: Code inside the message Event: https://pastebin.com/SNkMda2S

Comment: Are you sure that you're reaching to the `await role.edit...` line? Have you tried to put console.log before and after that line?

Comment: I've already tested that, the code runs up to role.edit without errors.